# VS Code command to open using terminal

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

When I try to run "code" on the terminal of my mac. It shows this error. What can could possibly cause this error?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AW8sd.png

Answer (score 0):

This should be caused by no permission on /usr/local/bin/code. If you can use:

`chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/code`

It should solve the issue.

You can also use below command to check the permission:

`ls -l /usr/local/bin/code`

Comment: Still the same warning that came out. Already restart the mac